# SEG fault in async_read_until()

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault

I am facing an issue in reading through boost::asio::async_read_until(). The server code I have been using is as follows:

```
boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
    boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_,buffer,DELIMITER,boost::bind(
                                                      &chat_session::handle_read_body,
                                                      shared_from_this(),
                                                      placeholders::error,
                                                      placeholders::bytes_transferred()
                                                     )
                              );

void chat_session::handle_read_body(const boost::system::error_code& error,std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{

    FILE_LOG(logINFO)<<"Entry chat_session::handle_read_body\n";
    FILE_LOG(logINFO)<<"Bytes Received:\t"<<bytes_transferred<<endl;
}
```

When my client send some data with delimiter, the server comes up with a dialog for segmentation fault and the file in the background opened is read_until.hpp.The control does not come to the handle_read_body() function.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
shared_from_this(),
```

`this` is your problem - pardon the pun.

Without seeing the crash, one of two things is probably happening:

a) Your code turns `shared_from_this()` into an rvalue from which a pointer is obtained, the shared object is then unref'd and the object gets destroyed after the callback has been queued,

b) The callback handler is trying to use the value of `shared_from_this()` to populate `this`, which is illegal (it doesn't know to call `shared_from_this().get()`)

You might want to try the following:

```
~chat_session()
{
    LOG("~chat_session(%p)", this);
}

// ...

auto ptr = shared_from_this();
LOG("this=%p, shared=%p, cs=%p, aru", this, ptr, (chat_session*)ptr);

boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_,buffer,DELIMITER,boost::bind(
                                                  &chat_session::handle_read_body,
                                                  ptr,
                                                  placeholders::error,
                                                  placeholders::bytes_transferred()
                                                 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But one more observation I want to put in is as follows: If DELIMITER is a char say '\n', then crash does not occur but the read_handler comes with bytes_transferred=0, and if DELIMITER is a string, then the crash occurs

Comment: Is this a local variable or a constant?

Comment: DELIMITER is a macro #define DELIMITER "END"

Comment: Hey guys, would anyone help me on this issue?